# Flutter cannot refresh GoogleMap after getting coordinates

Tags: flutter, google-maps, state

I have an app that implements GoogleMap.
I can go back to the page and get a nice map with premade settings, but I cannot make the map refresh when i press the button and nothing is set beforehand .

The widget is created on Build() and I have a button that gets the lat and lng from geolocator and also cityname reverse lookup.
That calls
SaveGPS() when it is done with everything.
I normally go directly from the Prefs.lat Prefs.lng, but I tried creating member variables _lng and _lat including a _zoom variable so that setState will work.. it does not work.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
    Container(
      width: 350,
      height: 350,
      child: GoogleMap(
          markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
          mapType: MapType.satellite,
          initialCameraPosition:
              CameraPosition(zoom: _zoom, target: LatLng(_lat, _lng))),
    ),
  void saveGps() async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    var timezoneOffset = now.timeZoneOffset;
    Prefs.cityName = _cityName;
    Prefs.offset = timezoneOffset.inMinutes / 60;

    setState(() {
      _lat = Prefs.lat = _position.latitude;
      _lng = Prefs.lng = _position.longitude;
      _markers.clear();
      _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(Prefs.cityName),
          position: LatLng(Prefs.lat, Prefs.lng),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: Prefs.cityName,
          )));
      _zoom = 17;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a map controller and did an animateCamera call.  This was the only way to make it work.  Other items update with setState but not this one.

```
// create this in your class
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

// build method here..
        Container(
          width: 350,
          height: 350,
          child: GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
              markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
              mapType: MapType.satellite,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  zoom: 16, target: LatLng(Prefs.lat, Prefs.lng))),
        ),
```

When you want to save the new map or display it,
call this code here:

```
final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
    CameraPosition(zoom: 17, target: LatLng(Prefs.lat, Prefs.lng))));
```